# AutoMapper unmapped Property by using expression mapping

Tags: c#, expression, automapper, iqueryable

I try to map business objects to persistence objects using expression mapping.

I was able to simplify the problem to this simple usage of AutoMapper.

Classes to map:

```
public class X
{
    public X(string name) => this.Name = name;

    public string Name { get; }
}

public class Y
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

These classes are very simple but shows the problem. X is immutable. That's no problem for AutoMapper. I created a map like:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg => 
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<X, Y>().ReverseMap();
    }); 
var mapper = mapperConfig.CreateMapper();
```

This works as expected in this case:

```
var yInstances = new List<Y> { new Y { Name = "Foo" } }; // Just to have some instances.
var xInstances = yInstances.Select(mapper.Map<X>).ToList();
```

As expected I got a List of `X`-Instances.

But I tried to use it as `IQueryable<T>` using expression mapping:

```
Expression<Func<X, bool>> filter = item => item.Name == "Foo";

// this line thows exception
yInstances.AsQueryable().Where(mapper.MapExpression<Expression<Func<Y, bool>>>(filter)).ToList();
```

The last line throws an exception containing this message:

```
Unhandled exception. AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException: 
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
=======
Y -> X (None member list)
Y -> X (None member list)

Unmapped properties:
Name
```

There is no unmapped property because `mapper.Map<X>` is working.

I tried to add `.ForCtorParam("name", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Name))`. But this doesn't work - not surprising.

What am I doing wrong? I'm pretty sure that this is only a single step but I'm unable to find it. Sorry.

The Code is on [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CaRnkq) that illustrates the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping/issues/46

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Sorry I don't get the point. There is no need to convert existing instances of `Y` to `X`. I don't need the _explicitly mapping the fields_. I only need a substitution from `X.Name == "Foo"` to `Y.Name == "Foo"`. Only accessing the values - not creating new ones. I thought that this is what [expression mapping](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html) does. The sample shows _Expression will be translated to `ol => ol.Item.Name.StartsWith("A")`_. And this is also valid for immutable types. What I'm missing?

Comment: Does the proposed workaround work?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Wow. I didn't realized that `.ForMember(dest => dest.Name, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Name));` is a proposed workarround. Sorry. Yes this works. Thx.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I have thought about it once again and now I got the point of _the mapping cannot exist_ from Taylor. In my case the expression contains only read access to the members. But expressions may contain a setter to that property and that's why _the mapping cannot exist_. Thanks for clearification.